# parse files on github / general advice on how to approach this better

Tags: php, github, lua

i wrote something that i tend to call a "parser" (no idea if that's the correct term)

all it currently does is grab a local lua file that has a lot of similarity with a json and remove / replace all contents that keep it from being an actual json.

process is something like:

1. search through all lua files with glob() / file_get_contents()
2. remove/replace (preg_replace/str_replace) everything from the file that keeps it from being a json
3. use json_decode() on the final thing
4. grab all info that I need and add to database
5. display data
   I used php for all these steps

These lua files can be retrieved from a guy that maintains it on github so I thought it would be a smart idea to just parse them right from the raw url.

Ideally I would need github to send me some kind of clue that the guy who maintains it sent an update and then I start parsing in order to automate that process.

Can this be done? Is there a better way to do this? Any pointers are welcome

Comment: "These lua files can be retrieved from a guy that maintains it on github so I thought it would be a smart idea to just parse them right from the raw url." - you haven't specified the file format...

Comment: it's a .lua file

Comment: Can you show us the file?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/Gethe/wow-ui-source/tree/live/Interface/AddOns/Blizzard_APIDocumentation)

idea is to parse all those files, look for functions (name, arguments, returns), events (name, payload) and add them to a database to have a summary of all functions / events that it offers.

Comment: You need a PHP library to be able to invoke a Lua script from PHP.  You should: 1) invoke a Lua script to create `APIDocumentation` object (you should write this script or someone here will write it in the answer); 2) Invoke Lua script downloaded from GitHub; 3) invoke Lua script to convert `APIDocumentation` object to JSON format (a lot of pure-Lua JSON implementations exist, even me has [one](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/json4lua/blob/master/json.lua) ); 4) Get JSON-string generated by Lua script to PHP side.

Comment: tbh it probably doesn't even need to be done with PHP. Goal is just to fill a database with all the functions / events that the .lua file offers.

then I can just display that data using php.

Comment: Then you might as well have Lua fill the database.

Comment: oh well... when you suddenly realize that lua can connect to a database

Comment: Phew. I just spent 8 hours trying to get luarocks to properly install luasql until I eventually gave up and found an "all in one solution" (https://github.com/rjpcomputing/luaforwindows)

jesus. well. atleast I made big progress...
created an APIDocumention object like suggested and it seems to work like a charm. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.